# android : when is webview ready to layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

My activity consists of a WebView and a couple buttons. I'm trying to display the buttons at the bottom of the activity, but ensure that the user must scroll through the content if it is taller than the screen.  As part of my solution I have set the WebView's layout_height attribute to wrap_content.

Problem is, even though I call WebView.loadData() from within onCreate(), the WebView does not size itself right away.  In the case where the web content is taller than the screen, the buttons initially appear at the bottom of the activity, and then move off-screen when the web content appears.  I want to prevent the buttons from appearing at all before the web content is sized, so that when they do appear they always appear in the right place.  To this end I have tried using onPageFinished (it gets called too early) and onPictureListener (it is never called at all).

How can I determine when the WebView is ready for layout?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.webkit.WebView
            android:id="@+id/wv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClickButton1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClickButton2" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock to have your buttons appear neatly.

Comment: Does ActionBarSherlock tell me when WebView has finished layout?